# Looking an example to create a db by cron

Tags: mysql, linux, cron

I would know if you have an example to create a cron allowing to remove a db and create a new db every hour.

Do you have an example.

`delete database test.sql` => remove all db table inside the db

`mysql test < fichier.sql` => import all db table.

```
# at every hour
0 0 0 0 *        mysql -e delete database; test.sql mysql test < fichier.sql
```

`drop table *` => remove all table inside the db

```
/usr/bin/mysql -e 'drop table * if exists c1_demo_client; create database test' && /usr/bin/mysql test < /var/www/home/web/www/test/db_demo_client/test_db.sql
```

Is correct ?
Thank you

Comment: Separate your commands with `;` or `&&` or write a script with multiple lines that does the job.

Comment: @tadman Changed, is it correct ? The cron time is correct ?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is within the `cron` environment you may not have a full `PATH` so it's usually a good idea to specify the explicit path to each thing, including input and output files. `/usr/bin/mysql` or `/usr/local/bin/mysql` or wherever that is, plus `< /home/.../fichier.sql` and so on.

Comment: ok see above, tk

Comment: BTW, you can't just make up SQL syntax you want. Validate it against the manuals for your MySQL version. So there is no `drop table *`

Answer (score 2):

[Deleting a database](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/drop-database/) is 'drop database {databasename}' which is odd to see `test.sql` in your crontab.

Suggest:

```
0 0 0 0 *        mysql -e 'drop database if exists test; create database test' && mysql test < fichier.sql
```

Comment: I don't want to drop the database, but to remove all inside. I changed the element above. Tell me if it's correct. TK

Comment: The easiest way to do that will be dropping and recreating it, as shown in this answer.

Comment: Ok I understand, but inside the db there is right for user. If I drop the dn, I lost the right. That's my problem.

Comment: Understandable, however the alternate deletion SQL will look excessive and future lack portability as features are added at database context. Recreating the user and database will be quicker/future proof. An explanation on why the hourly deletions occur might insight a broader rather of alternatives.

Comment: @mike You can easily re-issue the `GRANT` privileges as part of this process.